# Odd AD workstation access issue

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-7-x64, windows-server-2012-r2

After working with Windows Server since NT 3.51, this was kind of a first for me. Here's the scenario.

- After no issues accessing a Windows Server 2012 R2 network share for 2 years, a Win 7 Pro workstation all of a sudden can access the mapped drive to the share, but cannot see all subfolders underneath it. Only one is visible, not the other 20 or so.
- When I log out as the user and login as the domain admin account, the issue persists on the workstation. Just this one workstation.
- Nothing has changed in terms of the share or NTFS permissions on the server-side of things.
- I look in the server event logs as well as the workstation's and don't see anything striking.
- I removed the workstation from the domain and add it again. The issue still persists.
- The workaround is that I created a second share to the same resource on the server-side of things. Mapping a different drive letter to this new share, the workstation can see everything again.

My only guess would be some sort of old school SAM database corruption or something? I recall years ago I had a Windows 2000 Server that would lose Computer Browser functionality due to some odd SAM database corruption. The only solution back then was to reboot the server. It was the PDC and couldn't even browse its own network shares.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it might help to read [tour], and you might get more help for this question at sister site ServerFault.com

Comment: Now that I'm again looking at the server that is hosting the shares, I see Security event log errors. Unrelated to the network share with the one workstation having trouble accessing all the contents. There is a different share where the server itself (account name is DC-FS01$) cannot access the directory. It definitely had Full Access. The errors didn't go away after I reset the NTFS perms to what they were originally anyway. Odd...wondering what CLI utils I can run to perform a consistency check on things?

Comment: Security ID: SYSTEM
 Account Name: DC-FS01$
 Account Domain: DIAMOND_DOM
 Logon ID: 0x3E7
Object:
 Object Server: Security
 Object Type: File
 Object Name: C:\public\users\franks
 Handle ID: 0x0
 Resource Attributes: -
Process Information: Process ID:  0x2c4
 Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Access Request Information:
 Transaction ID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
 Accesses: ReadData (or ListDirectory)    
 Access Reasons: ReadData (or ListDirectory): Not granted    
 Access Mask: 0x1
 Privileges Used for Access Check: -
 Restricted SID Count: 0

Comment: I ran the Powershell commands listed here and no integrity issues were found --> http://www.rebeladmin.com/2018/03/integrity-check-detect-low-level-active-directory-database-corruption/.

Comment: It's also better to edit the question to add new information instead of adding comments.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the tips!